# Laravel validation запрос обновления уникального поля только в случае если значение уникальное или если значение не изменилось

Tags: laravel, валидация

нужно сделать так чтобы проверка прошла успешно если значение 'courts' в таблице 'name' уникальное или если оно не изменилось

```
Validation

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:courts,name'
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Документация: [unique:table,column,except,idColumn](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-unique)

Проверяем на уникальность, за исключением значения текущей (нужен `$id`) записи:

```
'name' => 'required|unique:courts,name,' . $id
```

Или посмотрите на `Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)` (в той же документации).